# Can an open thread border router (like raspberry pi + nrf52840) communicate with Google Home app?

Tags: multithreading, google-home, openthread, matter-iot-standard, nrf52840

I have successfully setup an open thread border router using a raspberry pi with nrf52840 USB dongle.

I have also implemented a light-bulb device using an nrf52840DK.

I am able to commission and control the light-bulb device using the chip-tool on raspberry or through the CHIPTool app.

I am trying to add light-bulb device on Google Home app, but it fails with the message "Your device requires a Thread border router". All of my devices (and my otbr) are in the same network.
Is it possible to use my "custom" otbr with Google Home app?

Thank you,
George

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this up. Yes, it is possible to have a 3p border router [participate](https://developers.home.google.com/thread#new_border_router_setups) in the thread network used by Google Home. However, you'll still need one of our supported Nest Hubs(2nd Gen) for device control to work.

There are two ways this might happen:

- The 3p thread border router is setup first, and an app sets the android phone's preferred credentials to that of the 3p thread border router
- The 3p thread border router is given the preferred credentials and joins the preferred network

If you setup 3p thread border router and give the correct credentials to android device, then commissioning should work. However, as said earlier, Nest Hub(2nd Gen) is required for device control to work.

Comment: Thank you @Armen for your reply.

I see in your reply that you are referring in app development. 

Is there a way to use an existing app (like Google Home) to control a 3p end Matter Thread device (light bulb) with a 3p OTBR in the same network. Matter controller (chip-tool) runs in 3p OTBR.